# Did Prophet Muhammad PBUH heal Salama ibn Akwa's leg wound when he breathed upon it? I’ve heard of this story during the battle of Khayber

Tags: hadith, source-identification

This happened during the same battle Ali eyes were cured the only problem is I can’t find the hadith where prophet Muhammad pbuh healed Salama ibn Akwa's leg wound when he breathed upon it.

Answer (score 1):

This is narrated in [Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:4206) and [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:3894), [Musnad Ahmad](https://shamela.ws/book/25794/12983) and [Sahih Ibn Hibban](https://al-maktaba.org/book/1729/9471):

> حدثنا يزيد بن أبي عبيد، قال: رأيت أثر ضربة في ساق سلمة فقلت: يا أبا مسلم، ما هذه الضربة؟ قال: هذه ضربة أصبتها يوم خيبر، قال: يوم أصبتها قال الناس: أصيب سلمة، " فأتي بي رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم فنفث فيه ثلاث نفثات ، فما اشتكيتها حتى الساعة
>
> Yazid b. Abi ‘Ubaid said :
>
> I saw a sign of injury in the shin of Salamah. I asked : What is this? He replied : I was afflicted. I was afflicted by it on the day of Khaibar. The people said : Salamah has been afflicted. I was then brought to the Prophet (ﷺ). He blew on me three times. I did not feel any pain up till now.